# html radiobuttons focused state?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, css-selectors

I am wondering if there is something in css similar to a selector in android xml:

`<item android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_hover_background" />`

I am working on html page with radiobuttons which will be working using the remote control (arrows <-, -> and OK button), so user should know which radio button is selected at the moment, so he could navigate and select what he want.
I was trying to use:

```
input:focus, input:hover{
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:3px;
        border-color: #ccc; 
    }
```

but I am not getting desired effect.

Any suggestions?

NOTE: pressed state works fine, selected or focused state is issue.

Comment: Your CSS looks fine and will apply to focused radio buttons.  Are you including other CSS files that might be overwriting your rule?  Maybe a reset or something like Twitter Bootstrap?  If so, just make sure you're including your CSS above AFTER any other reset CSS files, etc.

Comment: well, I have only one css, so this is not the case am afraid

Comment: Sorry, I misread and thought you just wanted it when focused.  If you want the selected option to change, add `input:checked` to the selector string.